# JQTouch toolbar with two buttons

Tags: jqtouch

JQTOUCH - Could anyone please help me understand, How can we place two buttons on the right side of the Toolbar?

```
<div class="toolbar ">
   <a class="button slide add Black clearcmd" id="infoButton" href="#">Clear</a>
      <h1>Toolbar with two buttons on right side</h1><a class="button slide" id="infoButton" href="#buttontwo">Button Two</a> <a class="button slide" id="infoButton" href="#buttonone">Button One</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the CSS is just for one... You'd have to position/style the second one manually. Sorry-